# Keeping track of memory usage in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Is there a way in javascript to keep track of memory used by an application? I am not thinking about browser extensions used to debug memory leaks etc, but to let an application keep track of it's own memory consumption, to be able to make a qualified decision on whether to release memory or not.

Comment: well there's the chrome shift+esc that shows the memory of each tab (which is in a different process, on the opposite of other browsers)

Comment: @Sebas The W8 task manager does the same for IE10.

Comment: There is nothing built into JavaScript that lets it know anything about memory.

Comment: Since JS is a garbage-collected langauge, you hardly can "release" memory. Also, for the same reasone there are no native mechanims to get such information.

Comment: Bergi: by releasing memory I mean deleting objects, arrays etc which should make the GC do the rest of the work.

Comment: Just structure your program in such a way than unnecessary data goes out of scope when no longer needed. Manually deleting data in GC VM most likely means you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> to be able to make a qualified decision on whether to release memory or not.

JavaScript has an automatic garbage collector for managing the memory. You cannot manually release memory nor call the garbage collector (like in java and c# , for example).

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the commentors regarding memory management in JS, there is an interesting feature called "WeakMaps" in ECMAScript 6 which  although not exactly what you were asking for, is related:

> "The canonical example for using weakmaps is to create an object
>   related to a particular DOM element. For example, jQuery maintains a
>   cache of objects internally, one for each DOM element that has been
>   referenced. Using a weakmap would allow jQuery to automatically free
>   up memory associated with a DOM element when it is removed from the
>   document."

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/06/ecmascript-6-collections-part-3-weakmaps/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla

Comment: They are a special data structure that simplifies the automatic garbage collection, but your answer has nothing to do with what the OP asked for.

Comment: True, but it's related. The OP is concerned with memory management - which isn't really the right question for JavaScript. But this feature may alleviate problems in the first place.